Jensen's inequality with affine combination
From page 217 of 'Convex functions' by Arthur Wayne Roberts, Dale Varberg (exercise F) i want proof that: $f \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is affine iff $ f(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i)\le \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if(x_i)$, for all $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n,x_1,...,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1$.
If $f$ is affine (i.e. $f(x)=mx+q$ with $m,q\in\mathbb{R}$) is obvious that $ f(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i)= \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if(x_i)$ but why conversely?

I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never accepted an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See What should I do when someone answers my question? and How does accepting an answer work? for more information.

Leave alone "accepting" , with 25 questions & 8 "upvotes" , there is some "Serious Dis-Symmetry" here , @MartinR , making that look weird.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$. Then $g(ax+(1-a)y)\le ag(x)+(1-a)g(y)$ and $g(0)=0$. Put $y=0$ to get $g(ax)\le ag(x)$ $\cdots$ (1). Put $a=\frac  1 x$ to get $g(1)\le \frac 1  xg(x)$ or $g(x) \ge xg(1)$ for $x >0$. On the other hand, $a=\frac   y x $ gives  $g(y)\le \frac y x g(x)$ and putting $x=1$ in (1) gives $g(y) \le y g(1)$ for all $y$ Thus, $g(y)=yg(1)$ and $f(y)=f(0)+yg(1)$ for all $y>0$. I will let you handle $y \le 0$.  [You could look at the function $g(-x)$ for this].

The important point (I think) is that the given inequality holds for all $\lambda_i \in \Bbb R$, and not only for $0 \le \lambda_i \le 1$ as in the definition of convexity. It might be worth to mention that explicitly

@MartinR Yes, that is precisely the point I have exploited.

It suffices to require that the inequality holds with $n=2$, i.e. that
$$ \tag{*}
 f(\lambda x + \mu y) \le \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y)
$$
for all $\lambda, \mu, x, y \in \Bbb R$ with $\lambda + \mu = 1$.
The important point is that (in contrast to the convexity definition) $\lambda $ and $\mu$ are not required to be nonnegative. This can be used to show that $(*)$ is in fact an equality.
If $\lambda > 0$ then we can use $(*)$ with
$$
 \tilde \lambda = \frac 1 \lambda \, \, \tilde \mu = -\frac{\mu}{\lambda} \, , \\
 \tilde x = \lambda x + \mu y \, , \, \tilde y = y \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 f(x) = f(\tilde \lambda \tilde x + \tilde \mu \tilde y) 
\le \tilde \lambda f(\tilde x) + \tilde \mu f(\tilde y) = \frac 1\lambda f(\lambda x + \mu y) - \frac{\mu}{\lambda}f(y)
$$
or
$$ \tag{**}
f(\lambda x + \mu y) \ge \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y) \, .
$$
If $\lambda \le 0$ then $\mu > 0$ and we can use the same argument with $\lambda$ and $\mu$ interchanged. So $(**)$ holds in any case.
Combining $(*)$  and $(**)$ we see that equality holds:
$$
f(\lambda x + \mu y) = \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y) 
$$
and in particular ($x=0, y=1$):
$$
f(\mu) = f(0) + \mu (f(1) - f(0)) \, .
$$

If $\lambda<0$, then $(**)$ is false.

@user791759: You are right, that was a stupid error. – Hopefully it is correct now.
